# What are some strategies for changing high level rules/procedures?

Tags: company-policy

I am a software developer for a large organization (10,000+ employees).

It seems often(perhaps intentionally)unpopular policies are made from top level executives.  The policies mostly effect us employees on the "ground floor".  Through middle management, we learn of these policies with the anecdote "our hands our tied, we didn't decide this".

The accountability breaks down because the executives never have to see the people their policies are affecting.  Middle managers want to look like team players so they don't relay frustrations with the policy to the executives.

**What are some strategies a low level employee can implement to institute change?**

Comment: Why the votes to close?  Please explain

Comment: The question is very broad.  You may be better to have a specific improvement and ask for suggestions on how to make that one work.

Answer (score 5):

In 99% of cases, the simple answer is "you can't do anything about it". It really is the case that the decision has been made, and it's always easier to leave things as they are rather than change something, particularly if that involves backtracking on an earlier decision.

Some things to note:

- An unpopular decision is not necessarily a bad one. To take a common example, laying off staff is never popular - but sometimes it is necessary for the business.
- If your middle managers really aren't relaying the concerns of their staff upwards, then **you have bad managers**. Trying to fix problems when the very people that should be supporting you aren't supporting you is probably a waste of time. On the other hand, it may be the case that your managers are relaying concerns upwards - but there are sometimes more important things than fixing every little concern from staff (see point 1).

Answer (score 3):

It is a difficult situation but things can be done.
You cannot overstep your position, so you have to convince your N+1 (your direct boss) and you need to give him the tools to convince his boss.

Say, a new directive from the top to the bottom is made in place and force you to log in another webpage everyday to log your time again.
You are impacted, as your fellow colleagues, but you feel this is unnecessary because this information can be found on another webpage.

I would advice to gather the number of people affected by this decision (roughtly), add up the number per day/week/month/year used up. Maybe investigate quickly around with technical people to know if this information is accessible somewhere, and what would be the cost of this access.

10 000 employes x 10 seconds (time to access the page and log the number) x 52 (weeks in one year) x 5(working days per week) => **903 days used per year**

903 x 5 years x 400 (average salary cost /day) = **1 805 555** $

cost to create a tool that do that automatically (multiply by 5 the number given by the technical guy): **300 000** $

Compelling number have a powerful ways with managers! Your boss will have one and a half million reason to go convince his boss.